# C# call perl and passing values

Tags: c#, perl

Hello I have a question with perl.

Now I have a code that calls a perl code from c#. Now what if I need to pass some values to perl code?

```
string arguments = @"C:\Users\Desktop\test.pl";

Process myProcess = Process.Start(fullPath, arguments);

myProcess.WaitForExit(999);

if (!myProcess.HasExited)
{

  myProcess.Kill();

  throw new Exception("Timed out while running process");

}
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

this is my c# code and perl code. to simplify, it just passes two variable and print to txt file.

namespace testperl

{

```
class Program

{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fullPath = @"C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe";

        string arguments = @"C:\Users\Desktop\old.pl"+"aa" + "bb";

        Process myProcess = Process.Start(fullPath, arguments);

        myProcess.WaitForExit(999);

        if (!myProcess.HasExited)
        {

            myProcess.Kill();

            throw new Exception("Timed out while running process");

        }

        Console.WriteLine("all set");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

### the perl code:

```
use strict;

use warnings;

use Carp;

use English qw(-no_match_vars);

my $files = 'report.txt';

if (-f $files) {
unlink $files
    or croak "Cannot delete $files: $!";
}

my $OUTFILE;

my ($name, $number) = @ARGV;

if (not defined $name) {

   die "Need name\n";
 }


 open $OUTFILE, '>>', $files

 or croak "Cannot open $files: $OS_ERROR";

 if (defined $number) {

    print { $OUTFILE } "thing, $name \n"

    or croak "Cannot write to $files: $OS_ERROR";
```

}

```
   close $OUTFILE

   or croak "Cannot close $files: $OS_ERROR";
```

Comment: Look at your `arguments` variable in c# code. You need spaces after filename `old.pl aa bb`

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in the arguments as

```
string arguments = @"C:\Users\Desktop\test.pl ARG1 ARG2";
```

(and then you can access them in Perl using `@ARGV`)

Comment: I am quite new to perl, is that a way that you can assign ARG1 and ARG2 to different variables in perl？

Comment: `@ARGV` is an array of comand line args provided when the script executed. See e.g. http://perlmaven.com/argv-in-perl

Comment: Hello rbm, I just pasted the code and still it does not work. Thx